# Scraping YouTube playlist video links

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I wanted to download all videos of [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5) Youtube channel. So I tried to write a script with `BeautifulSoup` to scrape all the links of the videos.

I did some inspection and found out that the "`tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile`" can be used to get the links. This is the Python code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5'
html=urllib2.urlopen(url)
response=html.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)
res=soup.find_all('tr',class_="pl-video yt-uix-tile ")
print res
```

But I am not able to get all the links. The output is empty. What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Your code returns 100 rows for me so there is nothing wrong with the logic, what version of bs4?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using Beautiful Soup version 4.3.2 and Python 2.7

Comment: Try upgrading, pip install -U bs4

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Tried upgrading too..now I am getting a partial output(18 links).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5')
page = r.text
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
res=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
for l in res:
    print l.get("href")
```

It is giving me output as below in pycharm:

```
/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&index=1&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=857zrsYZKGo&index=2&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Da1jlmwuW_w&index=3&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=MIKl8PX838E&index=4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=sPFUTJgvVpQ&index=5&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=maYFI5O6P-8&index=6&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=6moe-rLZKCk&index=7&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=eKXnQ83RU3I&index=8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=WjE-pWYElsE&index=9&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=hUA_isgpTHI&index=10&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=IHg_0HJ5iQo&index=11&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=H92G3CpSQf4&index=12&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=B5uJeno3xg8&index=13&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=hy0mRoT1ZlM&index=14&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Xpkbu2GrJpE&index=15&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=-G91Hp3t6sg&index=16&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=-zGS_zrL0rY&index=17&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=4LHIESO0NGk&index=18&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=8kybpxIixRk&index=19&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=eHh2Yib7u-A&index=20&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&index=21&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=ma8aUC-Mf5M&index=22&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=4MnuiIKCqsQ&index=23&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=gz6P2E9lkfo&index=24&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=roulejuE6B8&index=25&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=NyusGsXc6SQ&index=26&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=_joTj5XTwuQ&index=27&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=55G47PgDwkY&index=28&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=0MkeTcH0SPc&index=29&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=QjQg8NkHGbw&index=30&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=2CuTy8SA5kU&index=31&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=MC2WFgZIZjo&index=32&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=G_MkSpfKIPA&index=33&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Krt3g9HhhZ4&index=34&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=lIwTbp5N7Hw&index=35&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=geB8FqcUjo8&index=36&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Sqk154QSe8Y&index=37&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=nq3yUjZGj5c&index=38&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=8yA0vkjREyI&index=39&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=AlC_Z5w8nDE&index=40&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=2jduTfdt8RY&index=41&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=6AoBM110DAY&index=42&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=n6xhAVcopYU&index=43&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=P2tNi1tS0xU&index=44&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=AEA1qJFpheY&index=45&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=iA2Efmo2PCA&index=46&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=0-NTc0ezXes&index=47&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=jbUQyJdf2P8&index=48&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=zJ9qzvOOjAM&index=49&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=wRa5Q2Eloa4&index=50&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Df129IGl31I&index=51&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=SGx03Uqn9JA&index=52&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=oaNus5QigYA&index=53&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=fV3cpnNPWo0&index=54&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=zXXCFmfJMNw&index=55&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=iFoaqeEtTNU&index=56&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=UlOM-CUlsBc&index=57&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=XzTSdfLJt04&index=58&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=iMe4fW31jMs&index=59&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=BlKDYBqlfgs&index=60&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=kOJGmVXuuFA&index=61&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ&index=62&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=0wy907WZFiA&index=63&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=ZMcYbf9Hhe4&index=64&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=yowNavIDzzE&index=65&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=cJUsL7sc1E8&index=66&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&index=67&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=iZMNaPgP4Ak&index=68&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=PmOtvJqDfqY&index=69&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=ulFq_0x29sI&index=70&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Dmq_WGhJbgI&index=71&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=S36C23lW5qI&index=72&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=3r9NGjBvv2w&index=73&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=ioGWpu8Ud7A&index=74&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=K7YuusyEvOg&index=75&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=3OhGkg_XT3o&index=76&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=G8QK452ynr4&index=77&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=XVPCXNoiYIg&index=78&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=m1AeMJux0Zo&index=79&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=o5LrdSQrWEI&index=80&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=NcKSFlYEqYY&index=81&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=N2Tx8S2V8ek&index=82&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=Iy3wCppq2Yc&index=83&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=lkadcYQ6SuY&index=84&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=PQ94MmEg0Qw&index=85&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=DqNzTaf9g5w&index=86&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=BWGW8UsO4Hc&index=87&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=b4MYh6N4z6s&index=88&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=9xGIlaezMAU&index=89&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=UC2wAuxECw0&index=90&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=zRqcoUSbMI0&index=91&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=D2iMtK8ETGs&index=92&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=PJL8UChOsSk&index=93&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=QbD6qwxiEUU&index=94&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=-ZbdfYleuJU&index=95&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=JVaGZwuYmck&index=96&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=5pr7jwYF0JU&index=97&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=MNCAmgFHcOI&index=98&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=tXR0AlhNYxQ&index=99&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
/watch?v=GtWXOzsD5Fw&index=100&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5
```

And below output on cmd:

```
/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=1
/watch?v=857zrsYZKGo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=2
/watch?v=Da1jlmwuW_w&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=3
/watch?v=MIKl8PX838E&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=4
/watch?v=sPFUTJgvVpQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=5
/watch?v=maYFI5O6P-8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=6
/watch?v=6moe-rLZKCk&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=7
/watch?v=eKXnQ83RU3I&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=8
/watch?v=WjE-pWYElsE&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=9
/watch?v=hUA_isgpTHI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=10
/watch?v=IHg_0HJ5iQo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=11
/watch?v=H92G3CpSQf4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=12
/watch?v=B5uJeno3xg8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=13
/watch?v=hy0mRoT1ZlM&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=14
/watch?v=Xpkbu2GrJpE&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=15
/watch?v=-G91Hp3t6sg&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=16
/watch?v=-zGS_zrL0rY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=17
/watch?v=4LHIESO0NGk&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=18
/watch?v=8kybpxIixRk&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=19
/watch?v=eHh2Yib7u-A&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=20
/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=21
/watch?v=ma8aUC-Mf5M&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=22
/watch?v=4MnuiIKCqsQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=23
/watch?v=gz6P2E9lkfo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=24
/watch?v=roulejuE6B8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=25
/watch?v=NyusGsXc6SQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=26
/watch?v=_joTj5XTwuQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=27
/watch?v=55G47PgDwkY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=28
/watch?v=0MkeTcH0SPc&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=29
/watch?v=QjQg8NkHGbw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=30
/watch?v=2CuTy8SA5kU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=31
/watch?v=MC2WFgZIZjo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=32
/watch?v=G_MkSpfKIPA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=33
/watch?v=Krt3g9HhhZ4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=34
/watch?v=lIwTbp5N7Hw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=35
/watch?v=geB8FqcUjo8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=36
/watch?v=Sqk154QSe8Y&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=37
/watch?v=nq3yUjZGj5c&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=38
/watch?v=8yA0vkjREyI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=39
/watch?v=AlC_Z5w8nDE&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=40
/watch?v=2jduTfdt8RY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=41
/watch?v=6AoBM110DAY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=42
/watch?v=n6xhAVcopYU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=43
/watch?v=P2tNi1tS0xU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=44
/watch?v=AEA1qJFpheY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=45
/watch?v=iA2Efmo2PCA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=46
/watch?v=0-NTc0ezXes&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=47
/watch?v=jbUQyJdf2P8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=48
/watch?v=zJ9qzvOOjAM&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=49
/watch?v=wRa5Q2Eloa4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=50
/watch?v=Df129IGl31I&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=51
/watch?v=SGx03Uqn9JA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=52
/watch?v=oaNus5QigYA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=53
/watch?v=fV3cpnNPWo0&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=54
/watch?v=zXXCFmfJMNw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=55
/watch?v=iFoaqeEtTNU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=56
/watch?v=UlOM-CUlsBc&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=57
/watch?v=XzTSdfLJt04&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=58
/watch?v=iMe4fW31jMs&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=59
/watch?v=BlKDYBqlfgs&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=60
/watch?v=kOJGmVXuuFA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=61
/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=62
/watch?v=0wy907WZFiA&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=63
/watch?v=ZMcYbf9Hhe4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=64
/watch?v=yowNavIDzzE&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=65
/watch?v=cJUsL7sc1E8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=66
/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=67
/watch?v=iZMNaPgP4Ak&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=68
/watch?v=PmOtvJqDfqY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=69
/watch?v=ulFq_0x29sI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=70
/watch?v=Dmq_WGhJbgI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=71
/watch?v=S36C23lW5qI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=72
/watch?v=3r9NGjBvv2w&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=73
/watch?v=ioGWpu8Ud7A&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=74
/watch?v=K7YuusyEvOg&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=75
/watch?v=3OhGkg_XT3o&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=76
/watch?v=G8QK452ynr4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=77
/watch?v=XVPCXNoiYIg&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=78
/watch?v=m1AeMJux0Zo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=79
/watch?v=o5LrdSQrWEI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=80
/watch?v=NcKSFlYEqYY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=81
/watch?v=N2Tx8S2V8ek&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=82
/watch?v=Iy3wCppq2Yc&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=83
/watch?v=lkadcYQ6SuY&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=84
/watch?v=PQ94MmEg0Qw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=85
/watch?v=DqNzTaf9g5w&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=86
/watch?v=BWGW8UsO4Hc&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=87
/watch?v=b4MYh6N4z6s&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=88
/watch?v=9xGIlaezMAU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=89
/watch?v=UC2wAuxECw0&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=90
/watch?v=zRqcoUSbMI0&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=91
/watch?v=D2iMtK8ETGs&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=92
/watch?v=PJL8UChOsSk&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=93
/watch?v=QbD6qwxiEUU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=94
/watch?v=-ZbdfYleuJU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=95
/watch?v=JVaGZwuYmck&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=96
/watch?v=5pr7jwYF0JU&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=97
/watch?v=MNCAmgFHcOI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=98
/watch?v=tXR0AlhNYxQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=99
/watch?v=GtWXOzsD5Fw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=100
```

I am using Python 2.7.12 and beautifulsoup4

Comment: Your code works in my system too.Any idea why any other code is not working?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user6739649, i am not getting any output when running other code given by Meysam.

Comment: @user6739649. The reason for the same is the way parsing the done in "lxml" and "html.parser" is different see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#differences-between-parsers for more details.when I do print of soup in Meysam code and try to find the class "pl-video-title-link" it is returning me 0 result while when I am doing the print of soup in my code & searching same class it is showing me all 100 results as expected. I did around 10 iterations on other code and I only got blank output

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlParser = "lxml"
url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5'
html=urllib2.urlopen(url)
response=html.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response, htmlParser)
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
for a in links:
    print(a.get("href"))
```

Output:

> /watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=1
>   /watch?v=857zrsYZKGo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=2
>   /watch?v=Da1jlmwuW_w&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=3
>   /watch?v=MIKl8PX838E&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=4
>   /watch?v=sPFUTJgvVpQ&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=5
>   /watch?v=maYFI5O6P-8&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=6
>   /watch?v=6moe-rLZKCk&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=7
>   /watch?v=eKXnQ83RU3I&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=8
>   /watch?v=WjE-pWYElsE&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=9
>   /watch?v=hUA_isgpTHI&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=10
>   /watch?v=IHg_0HJ5iQo&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=11
>   /watch?v=H92G3CpSQf4&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=12
>   ...

Comment: I am not getting the entire list of the links in my output.Just the first few(17) videos alone come in the output.I used the same code you have put in the answer.How can I fix this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user6739649 I am getting 100 links. I don't know why your are getting only 17. Don't you get any error?

Comment: No errors.Which version of Python are you using?I am getting 17 links only if I execute the script in command line.If I run it as a script, I am getting [] as the output.

Comment: @user6739649 The version I am using is 2.7.6

Comment: @user6739649 oh this is very old. Sorry. Buffer seems the culprit. Increasing the buffer in the CMD for anyone trying to find solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Try This-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getPlaylistLinks(url):
    sourceCode = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sourceCode, 'html.parser')
    domain = 'https://www.youtube.com'
for link in soup.find_all("a", {"dir": "ltr"}):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href.startswith('/watch?'):
        print(link.string.strip())
        print(domain + href + '\n')

getPlaylistLinks('Your URL')
```